# Virtual printer : intercept data sent to printer using c#

Tags: c#, printing, pdf-generation, ghostscript, redmon

i'm creating a PDF Creator equivalent and I have to add some options to it while using C# language.

I would like to know how I can intercept data that was sent to the printer and how I can save it in a c# variable.

My printer launches the program as follows. Redmon is used as a redirection port
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program's like Redmon allow you to save the data to file.  Save it as a temp file then pass in the filename as a command line argument.  You could also pass it in as stdin/stdout which is how Redmon passes it into Ghostscript but temp file solution should work well and is easy to implement.